# Как обойти HTTP Error 429?

Tags: python, json, useragent

Я столкнулся с проблемой,а именно с обходом ограничения запроса в данной ссылке `https://www.instagram.com/'+ parse +'/?__a=1'`.Я пробовал обойти через подмену User-agent,но у меня ничего не получилось

```
import json
import urllib.request
 
 
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'
}
 
url = 'https://www.instagram.com/zuck/?__a=1'
rq = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=headers)
 
data1 = urllib.request.urlopen(rq)
data = json.loads(data1.read())
print("id",data['graphql']['user']['id'])
```

Comment: Добавьте в код как вы заголовок User-Agent указывали

Comment: @gil9red Добавил

Comment: Там получится `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'timeout'`, не уверен, что в urlopen можно кортеж передавать. Да и `data` вернет объект `Response` и это вызовет ошибку при `json.loads(data)`. Вот так работает: https://pastebin.com/BpArZy93

Comment: @gil9red Спасибо за ответ!Но у меня ошибка на выходе в переменной ```data = urllib.request.urlopen(rq)``` -```<http.client.HTTPResponse object at 0x0000017E09EDD1F0>```

Comment: Это не ошибка, а текстовое представление объекта, вангую, что у вас там `print(data)`

Comment: @gil9red Да,я подумал,что это некорректный вопрос,но в конечном результате у меня выбивает ошибку  **json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)**

Comment: Наверное, в ответе пришел невалидный, с точки зрения json, ответ. Выведите `text = data.read()` `print(text)`. Кст, сомневаюсь, что смена User-Agent повлияет на 429, там скорее всего просто по IP проверяется

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[HTTP 429 Too Many Requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429) код ответа указывает, что пользователь отправил слишком много запросов за последнее временя ("ограничение скорости" или "rate limiting" ).

Обойти можно:

- сделать паузы между запросами;
- менять user-agent;
- менять ip через [proxies](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#proxies)

Но 429 можно встретить и при единичном запросе:

```
>>> import requests
>>> url = 'https://www.instagram.com/geeks_for_geeks/'
>>> headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'}
>>> r = requests.get(url, headers)
>>> r
<Response [429]>
```

а при указании `headers=headers`:

```
>>> r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
>>> r
<Response [200]>
```

Comment: 2 последних пункта скорее вместе должны быть)

Comment: @alex совсем не обязательно, встречал пару сайтов, которые после смены только user-agent можно было продолжать парсить