# Как избежать ошибки How to avoid HTTP error 429?

Tags: python

Всем доброго времени суток. У меня возникает ошибка  `How to avoid HTTP error 429` при парсенге страниц гугл. Помогите посоветуйте как избежать данную ошибку всем спасибо за внимание жду вашей помощи.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22786068/how-to-avoid-http-error-429-too-many-requests-python здесь ответили на этот вопрос, правда на английском

Comment: В каком месте какой ответ из всех является верным?

Comment: @Авдошка самый заплюсованный ответ во всём своём тексте, как минимум.

Comment: Это равносильственно тому что вода мокрая, небо голубое, огонь горячий, снег холодный. Это не конкретный ответ на мой вопрос.

Comment: Я не кого не бомблю и не спамлю просто разрабатываю приложение на python. Почему вместо ответа на поставленный вопрос вы обвиняете меня в спаме? Мне просто нужно знать как устранить эту проблему а вы даете ответы методом тыка в  небо.

Comment: Очень просто - кешируйте запрошенные страницы, реже запрашивайте их с сервера. Возможно, Вам нужно научится писать юнит тесты.

Comment: Спасибо за внимание но ответ я нашел сам в данной (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1237263/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-http-error-429?rq=1) ветке

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как обойти HTTP Error 429?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1237263/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-http-error-429)